# Exception type Future(void) in not subtype of Future<AnimationController>

Tags: flutter, future, futuretask

the code below performs the creation of a layout in flutter, to create the layout I must first make sure that the set function is executed to make it use future builder but when I run the code I have the following error.
It tells me that the following error is present, future  is not a subtype of future ,
theoretically both derive from object so there shouldn't be inheritance problems on dart, what is this due to?

**Error:**

> type Future(void) in not subtype of Future

**Flutter Code:**

```
import ...

double latitudine=0;

Future<void> setValori() async {
   latitudine=await Gps.getLatitudine();
    print("Latitudine: "+latitudine.toString());
    print("\n \n Sono dentro set valori \n \n");


}

class MediterranesnDietView extends StatelessWidget {
  final AnimationController animationController;
  final Animation animation;

  const MediterranesnDietView(
      {Key key, this.animationController, this.animation})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return FutureBuilder<AnimatedBuilder>(
       future: setValori(),
       builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<AnimatedBuilder> snapshot) {
         return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: animationController,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return FadeTransition(
          opacity: animation,
          child: new Transform(
            transform: new Matrix4.translationValues(
                0.0, 30 * (1.0 - animation.value), 0.0),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 24, right: 24, top: 16, bottom: 18),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: FintnessAppTheme.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(8.0),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(68.0)),
                  boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: FintnessAppTheme.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                        offset: Offset(1.1, 1.1),
                        blurRadius: 10.0),
                  ],
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, left: 16, right: 16),
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 8, right: 8, top: 4),
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Container(
                                        height: 48,
                                        width: 2,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: HexColor('#87A0E5')
                                              .withOpacity(0.5),
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(4.0)),
                                        ),
                                      ),

                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                        child: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Padding(
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                  left: 4, bottom: 2),
                                              child: Text(
                                                'Latitudine',
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontFamily:
                                                      FintnessAppTheme.fontName,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                                  fontSize: 16,
                                                  letterSpacing: -0.1,
                                                  color: FintnessAppTheme.grey
                                                      .withOpacity(0.5),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            Row(
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                                  CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                              children: <Widget>[
                                                SizedBox(
                                                  width: 28,
                                                  height: 28,
                                                  child: Image.asset(
                                                      "assets/Home/eaten.png"),
                                                ),
                                                Padding(
                                                  padding:
                                                      const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                          left: 4, bottom: 3),
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    '${(latitudine * animation.value).toInt()}',
                                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontFamily:
                                                          FintnessAppTheme
                                                              .fontName,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.w600,
                                                      fontSize: 16,
                                                      color: FintnessAppTheme
                                                          .darkerText,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                Padding(
                                                  padding:
                                                      const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                          left: 4, bottom: 3),
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    '',
                                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontFamily:
                                                          FintnessAppTheme
                                                              .fontName,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.w600,
                                                      fontSize: 12,
                                                      letterSpacing: -0.2,
                                                      color: FintnessAppTheme
                                                          .grey
                                                          .withOpacity(0.5),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 8,
                                  ),
                                  Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Container(
                                        height: 48,
                                        width: 2,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: HexColor('#F56E98')
                                              .withOpacity(0.5),
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(4.0)),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                        child: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Padding(
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                  left: 4, bottom: 2),
                                              child: Text(
                                                'Longitudine',
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontFamily:
                                                      FintnessAppTheme.fontName,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                                  fontSize: 16,
                                                  letterSpacing: -0.1,
                                                  color: FintnessAppTheme.grey
                                                      .withOpacity(0.5),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            Row(
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                                  CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                              children: <Widget>[
                                                SizedBox(
                                                  width: 28,
                                                  height: 28,
                                                  child: Image.asset(
                                                      "assets/Home/burned.png"),
                                                ),
                                                Padding(
                                                  padding:
                                                      const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                          left: 4, bottom: 3),
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    '${(102 * animation.value).toInt()}',
                                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontFamily:
                                                          FintnessAppTheme
                                                              .fontName,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.w600,
                                                      fontSize: 16,
                                                      color: FintnessAppTheme
                                                          .darkerText,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                Padding(
                                                  padding:
                                                      const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                          left: 8, bottom: 3),
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    'Kcal',
                                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontFamily:
                                                          FintnessAppTheme
                                                              .fontName,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.w600,
                                                      fontSize: 12,
                                                      letterSpacing: -0.2,
                                                      color: FintnessAppTheme
                                                          .grey
                                                          .withOpacity(0.5),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Stack(
                                overflow: Overflow.visible,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Container(
                                      width: 100,
                                      height: 100,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: FintnessAppTheme.white,
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                          Radius.circular(100.0),
                                        ),
                                        border: new Border.all(
                                            width: 4,
                                            color: FintnessAppTheme
                                                .nearlyDarkBlue
                                                .withOpacity(0.2)),
                                      ),
                                      child: Column(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Text(
                                            '${(1503 * animation.value).toInt()}',
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontFamily:
                                                  FintnessAppTheme.fontName,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                              fontSize: 24,
                                              letterSpacing: 0.0,
                                              color: FintnessAppTheme
                                                  .nearlyDarkBlue,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            'Kcal left',
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontFamily:
                                                  FintnessAppTheme.fontName,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 12,
                                              letterSpacing: 0.0,
                                              color: FintnessAppTheme.grey
                                                  .withOpacity(0.5),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                    child: CustomPaint(
                                      painter: CurvePainter(
                                          colors: [
                                            FintnessAppTheme.nearlyDarkBlue,
                                            HexColor("#8A98E8"),
                                            HexColor("#8A98E8")
                                          ],
                                          angle: 140 +
                                              (360 - 140) *
                                                  (1.0 - animation.value)),
                                      child: SizedBox(
                                        width: 108,
                                        height: 108,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 24, right: 24, top: 8, bottom: 8),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 2,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: FintnessAppTheme.background,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 24, right: 24, top: 8, bottom: 16),
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  'Carbs',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: FintnessAppTheme.fontName,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    letterSpacing: -0.2,
                                    color: FintnessAppTheme.darkText,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                                  child: Container(
                                    height: 4,
                                    width: 70,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color:
                                          HexColor('#87A0E5').withOpacity(0.2),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                          Radius.circular(4.0)),
                                    ),
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Container(
                                          width: ((70 / 1.2) * animation.value),
                                          height: 4,
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                                              HexColor('#87A0E5'),
                                              HexColor('#87A0E5')
                                                  .withOpacity(0.5),
                                            ]),
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                                Radius.circular(4.0)),
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6),
                                  child: Text(
                                    '12g left',
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: FintnessAppTheme.fontName,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                      fontSize: 12,
                                      color: FintnessAppTheme.grey
                                          .withOpacity(0.5),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          ...
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
       );
       });
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Can you please only have code relevant to the error? You should get the line at which you're getting in your output in the debug console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates, that the Future you are giving the `FutureBuilder` does not match the Builders generic type.

You defined `FutureBuilder<AnimatedBuilder>` with the generic parameter `AnimatedBuilder` and it expects a `Future<AnimatedBuilder>`. The function `setValori()` is returning a `Future<void>`.

If you change your `FutureBuilder<AnimatedBuilder>` to `FutureBuilder<void>` and change `AsyncSnapshot<AnimatedBuilder>` to `AsyncSnapshot<void>`, you resolved the issues.

Answer (score 0):

As your method setValori() returns a Future of type void you need to change the following line:

```
return FutureBuilder<AnimatedBuilder>
```

this should be

```
return FutureBuilder<void>
```